# Determine deployed extensionBundle version

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I configured an Azure Function App for Windows with some version range for `extensionBundle` as recommended via `host.json`.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.0.0, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Is there s way to determine, which version of the bundle is actually used by the deployed Function App ?

With the concrete version of the bundle, I could also determine the versions of the specific extensions (see bundle [releases](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/releases)).

---

I thought, there is a way using the Kudu console. But I wasn't able to find the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can find the exact extension bundle version of Azure function app in KUDU site***.

- I have created a **dotnet Http triggered Azure function app** in Portal.

**Host.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

- To determine the extension bundle of function app, navigate to its KUDU site`(https://kpfnc.scm.azurewebsites.net)`=>**Debug Console=>LogFiles=>Application=>Functions=>Host=> select the log file, click on edit**:

[image]

- ***The extension bundle version can be seen in the logs as shown below:***

```
2024-02-08T10:49:27.320 [Information] Loading functions metadata
2024-02-08T10:49:27.321 [Information] Reading functions metadata (Custom)
2024-02-08T10:49:27.321 [Information] 1 functions found (Custom)
2024-02-08T10:49:27.321 [Information] 0 functions loaded
2024-02-08T10:49:27.324 [Information] Loading functions metadata
2024-02-08T10:49:27.324 [Information] Reading functions metadata (Custom)
2024-02-08T10:49:27.324 [Information] 1 functions found (Custom)
2024-02-08T10:49:27.324 [Information] 0 functions loaded
2024-02-08T10:49:27.647 [Information] Host Status: {
  "id": "kpfnc",
  "state": "Running",
  "version": "4.29.1.21919",
  "versionDetails": "4.29.1+593186e4f90d7XXXXXXXXX038b056d7",
  "platformVersion": "101.0.7.497",
  "instanceId": "e13d73201f7b06486557eXXXXXXXXXXX43a902b842cd6f4ab87e47",
  "computerName": "10-30-14-57",
  "processUptime": 238078,
  "functionAppContentEditingState": "Unknown",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "4.12.0"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to accepted answer, you can also use the ***Console*** view (*Development Tools* section) of your Function App in the Azure Portal directly.

```
> cd C:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host
> grep -A1 -e 'ExtensionBundle' *.log
2024-02-12T07-24-22Z-575394f180.log:    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
2024-02-12T07-24-22Z-575394f180.log-    "version": "4.12.0"
[..]
```

The example output points to the release [4.12.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/releases/tag/4.12.0).